# how to handle JSON_VAL() result set in CrudRepository hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc, db2

Could some one help me how to read result set from JSON_VAL() in db2. I am having the below db2 query which am executing from CrudRepository named query from hibernate.

```
  SELECT SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(data) FROM TABLE WHERE JSON_VAL(data,'column','s:25')=:value
```

Could some one help me how can I read the value.

My Hibernate repository class is

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, Integer> {    
    @Query(value = "SELECT SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(data) FROM TABLE WHERE JSON_VAL(data,'column','s:25')=:value", nativeQuery = true)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Clob findById(@Param("idd") String id);  
}
```

thanks in advance .